# Called function has undefined arguments when running with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

does someone have encountered the same issue?
I'm running jest with babel-jest and correct webpack-aliases configured in jest.config.js

But when I run the test, I see the next behavior
history object  (imported) is correctly defined in index.js and passed as an argument to a configureStore({history}) function

But inside the function it became undefined. Checked multiple times with debugger.

I tried to disable all mocks via jest.disableAutomock() and even in jest.config.js but nothing happens. I still see this behavior. And obviously, later when code tries to execute history.location I'm getting an exception, cuz it's undefined

```
// For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: false,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage',
  verbose: true,
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/__mocks__/setupJest.js'],
  transform: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileTransformer.js',

    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  globals: {
    NODE_ENV: 'test',
    APP_ENV: 'test',
    GIT_VERSION: 1
  },
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules'
  ],
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],

  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/public'],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.css$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    '^common-styles(.*)$': '<rootDir>/public/styles$1',
    '^styles(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/styles$1',
    '^reducers(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/reducers$1',
    '^store(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/store$1',
    '^middlewares(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/middlewares$1',
    '^newComponents(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/newComponents$1',
    '^components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/components$1',
    '^containers(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/containers$1',
    '^layouts(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/layouts$1',
    '^routes(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/routes$1',
    '^pages(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/pages$1',
    '^sagas(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/sagas$1',
    '^services(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/services$1',
    '^utils(.*)$8': '<rootDir>/js/utils$1',
    '^hocs(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/hocs$1',
    '^hooks(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/hooks$1',
    '^locales(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/locales$1',
    '^api(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/api$1',
    '^schemas(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/utils/schemas$1',
    '^constants(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/constants$1',
    '^src/featureToggles$': '<rootDir>/js/featureToggles.json',
    '^src$': '<rootDir>/js',
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/$1'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
}
```

babelrc

```
// Babel configuration
// https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env', {
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        corejs: 3,
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
    [
      'transform-imports',
      {
        'react-router': {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          transform: 'react-router/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true
        }
      }
    ],
    'transform-react-remove-prop-types'
  ],
  ignore: ['node_modules'],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
    }
  }
}
```

The test itself

```
import { alphabeticalSortWithProp } from 'routes/CustomerContent/helpers'

test('sorts objects by property desc', () => {
  const entries = [{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }]
  const expected = [{ name: 'C' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'A' }]
  const result = alphabeticalSortWithProp('name', 'desc')(entries)

  expect(expected).toEqual(result)
})
```

The tested file

```
import { ROOT_FOLDER_ID } from 'constants/common'
import * as R from 'ramda'
import { history } from 'utils/history'

export const alphabeticalSortWithProp = (propName, type) =>
  R.compose(
    R.sort,
    sortStrategy(type),
    sortNormalization
  )(propName)
```

History file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { globalDispatch } from 'src/index'
import { showRouteLeaveWarning } from 'utils/actions'

export const history = createBrowserHistory({
  getUserConfirmation: (message, callback) => globalDispatch(showRouteLeaveWarning({
    cancelHandler: () => callback(false),
    submitHandler: () => callback(true)
  }))
})
```

and the index.js containing globalDispatch

```
import 'locales'

/* global GIT_VERSION */

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import sagaMiddleware from 'middlewares/sagaMiddleware'
import rootSaga from 'sagas'
import configureStore from 'store/configureStore'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { initializeAnalytycs } from 'utils/analytics/init'
import { history } from 'utils/history'
import GlobalStyles from 'utils/styles/global'
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser'
import { ERROR_SETTINGS } from 'utils/sentry'

import 'normalize.css'
import 'flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.css'
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'
import 'common-styles/fonts.css'
import 'common-styles/tooltip.css'
import 'common-styles/safari.css'
import 'common-styles/slider.css'
import 'common-styles/react_slick_custom.css'
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css'
import 'rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import 'react-spinner/react-spinner.css'

import BootStrapApp from './BootStrapApp.js'

// initialize raven for reporting the uncaught exception to sentry for all the env except development
if (!['development', 'test'].includes(process.env.APP_ENV)) {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: process.env.SENTRY_KEY,
    environment: process.env.APP_ENV,
    release: GIT_VERSION,
    ...ERROR_SETTINGS
  })
}

const store =
  window.Store ||
  configureStore(
    {
      history
    },
    window.__initialState__
  )

window.Store = store

export const globalDispatch = store.dispatch

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

initializeAnalytycs()

if (module.hot) module.hot.accept()

const renderApp = RootComponent => {
  render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <RootComponent />
          <GlobalStyles />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )
}

renderApp(BootStrapApp)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you copy-paste the test code and the tested code. It will be easier to see the problem that way

Comment: @litelite added all the dependencies which can affect the test. So actually, you can see in index.js the following line 
const store =
  window.Store ||
  configureStore(
    {
      history
    },
    window.__initialState__
  )

Which is defined on run, but then, inside of the function it gets undefined.